# Delphi find xml node

Tags: xml, delphi, find

I'm trying do solve a very simple thing here: I want to find a node by name and read its text.

```
Function GetNodeText(xml,targetNode,value:string):String;
var
  xmldoc : IXMLDocument;
  root:    IXMLNode;
  i: LongInt;
  x:integer;
  s: string;
begin
  xmlDoc := newXMLDocument;
  xmlDoc.LoadFromXML(xml);
  xmlDoc.Active := true;

  root := XMLDoc.DocumentElement;

  for i := 0 to xmlDoc.ChildNodes[root.NodeName].ChildNodes.Count -1 do
  begin
    s := xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[i].NodeName;
    x := CompareStr(s, targetNode);
    if x = 0 then //targetnode Node found
    begin
      try
        result := xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[i].ChildNodes.FindNode(value).Text;
      Except
        result := '';
      end;
      exit;
    end
  end
end;
```

My function works only for the childs of the rootNode. How can I browse through ALL of the existing nodes of an XML document until I reach the end ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Customers>
    <customer>
        <id>1</id>          
        <Name>Ali</Name>
        <Age>34</Age>
        <favourite_car>
            <manufacturer>Porsche</manufacturer>
        </favourite_car>
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <Name>Hakan</Name>
        <id>2</id>          
        <Age>35</Age>
        <favourite_car>
            <manufacturer>BMW</manufacturer>
            <stack>overflow</stack>
        </favourite_car>
    </customer>
</Customers>
```

Comment: Can't tell without seeing the XML structure.

Comment: If the target node can appear anywhere in the XML at any level, then you have to use a recursive search or an XPath query to find it.

Comment: Hi,
I have added the XML structure. As you can see, it is very simple. I am interested in the manufacturers. But my code only looks for Name and Age.

Comment: Your xml structure doesn't look sensible. Each customer should be in a <customer> node, not <customer_1> .. <customer_n> nodes. Differentiation would be done by <Name> or by a new field, e.g. <id>. Please give an example (using the xml data sample) of what you would pass as `targetNode` and `value` to GetNodeText and what you would expect to be returned. Did you already try a recursive search, as Remy suggested?

Comment: Hi,
I have updated the xml structure accordingly. On the basis of this structure, I would like to search for a node called "stack" and get its value.

As Remy already stated, this node could appear anywhere in the structure. Thats why I tried to search for all nodes until I find the one with the desired name.

Hmm I did not try a recursive search yet, but I'll give it a try now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recursive node search was a great hint. I was able to build a solution, with the help of another thread:

```
function RecursiveFindNode(ANode: IXMLNode; const SearchNodeName: string): String;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if CompareText(ANode.NodeName, SearchNodeName) = 0 then
    begin
      if Assigned(ANode) then result := ANode.Text;
    end
  else if not Assigned(ANode.ChildNodes) then Result := ''
  else begin
    for I := 0 to ANode.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
    begin
      Result := RecursiveFindNode(ANode.ChildNodes[I], SearchNodeName);
      if Result  <> '' then Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: How would you use this function to find Hakans favourite_car manufacturer?

Comment: Downvoted because the check for Assigned(ANode) is misplaced. To prevent AV's due to nil being passed for ANode you need to do the check before you use ANode.

Answer (score 3):

A little bit changed version of the above function. Instead of returning Text, it returns IXMLNode.

```
function RecursiveFindNode(
  ANode: IXMLNode; const SearchNodeName: string): IXMLNode;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := nil;             
  if not Assigned(ANode) then
    exit;

  if CompareText(ANode.NodeName, SearchNodeName) = 0 then
    Result := ANode
  else
    if Assigned(ANode.ChildNodes) then
      for I := 0 to ANode.ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
      begin
        Result := RecursiveFindNode(ANode.ChildNodes[I], SearchNodeName);
        if Result <> nil then
          Exit;
      end;
end;
```